# Как и с чем можно сконвертировать базы в mysql с cp1251 в utf8?

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование

Имеются базы размером более 30GB, необходимо перевести схемы в utf8 и также сконвертировать данные.
Есть у кого идеи как оптимальнее всего это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое не прокатит? Замените cp1251 на utf8

http://it.w-develop.com/kak-izmenit-kodirovku-mysql-bazy-dannyx-ili-tablicy-nastrojka-collation-dlya-raboty-s-mysql/

При запросе к базе данных желательно задать Кодировку с которой будет работать клиент с сервером:

```
set character_set_client='utf8'
set character_set_results='utf8'
set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'
```

Изменяем кодировку для базы данных:

```
ALTER DATABASE `имя базы` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Изменяем кодировку для таблицы:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Я ничего не утверждал, я просто предложил попробовать предлагаемый вариант

Comment: Дело в том, что информацию по приведенной вами ссылке могут удалить. В таком случае, никто в будущем не сможет воспользоваться ответом. Пожалуйста, добавьте суть рекомендаций в ваш ответ.

Answer (score -2):

С помощью mysqldump и заменой в дампе DEFAULT CHARSET.

Comment: вы представляете, сколько это займет и сколько будет весит?

Comment: можно не полный дамп базы делать. А только тех столбцов, которым это актуально. 30гигов - там скорее всего картинки хранятся:)

Comment: это вы где видели чтобы в базе хранили статику, бред не несите =)

Comment: @lex0, это (обычно) крайне неправильный, но реальный случай